# распознование речи и фрагмент

Tags: android, распознавание-речи

Работаю над приложением где пользователь сможет листать страницы (использую Fragment) и нажимать на кнопки для запуска voice recognition, при этом voice recognition должен распознавать и сравнивать слова. Проблема в том, что не могу разобраться как использовать Fragment для пролистывания и распознавание слов вместе.

Если экстендую от FragmentActivity, подчеркивает onCreateView. Если экстендую от Fragment (как в коде ниже), подчеркивает onActivityResult.

Кто-нибудь может мне помочь правильно определить метод? Буду черезвычайно признателен :)

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment{

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_1_fragment_1, container, false);

    ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.voiceRecognition1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });

    final TextView frag1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.frag_1_frag_1);
    final TextView frag1ru = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.frag_1_frag_1_ru);

    frag1ru.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (frag1.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                frag1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                frag1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {//Выделяет красным RESULT_OK
        ArrayList<String> results;
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        TextView speechText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);//Выделяет красным findViewById
        String str="";
        for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){
            str+= results.get(i);
        }
        if (str.equals("five")) {
            speechText.setText(str);
        }else{
            speechText.setText("It's not: " + str);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Вы путаете lifecycle активити и фрагмента. Для начала определитесь на чем вы хотите строить свой UI, на активити или фрагментах? В случае если на activity, то код из метода фрагмента **onCreateView** перенесите в метод активити onCreate(), там единственное надо будет заменить строку

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_1_fragment_1, container, false);
```

на

```
setContentView(R.layout.frag_1_fragment_1);
```

Если же на фрагментах будете строить, то переделок немного больше, прежде всего это связано с передачей результатов из метода активити **onActivityResult** во фрагмент, но тоже все вполне возможно, просто учтите что onActivityResult - метод активити, а не фрагмента.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Когда изменяю onCreateView на onCreate, появляется ошибка в адаптере switch/case. Решил попробывать построить на фрагментах, не подскажете, какой метод использовать вместо onActivityResult?

Comment: не вижу в коде адаптера... но на самом деле в активити меньше переделок нужно, если же все таки фрагмент, то тогда в методе активити onActivityResult нужно поднять ссылку на фрагмент и уже у фрагмента вызвать что-то наподобие fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data), передавая во фрагмент параметры, полученные в колбеке активити. Понятно же, что у фрагмента нужно создать новый метод onActivityResult? А тот код, что у вас сейчас в этом методе нужно передвинуть во фрагмент. имхо с активити возни меньше